# Bith pip and pip3 direct to pip3 in the bash commandline

Tags: command-line, bash, python, pip

I am using Ubuntu and I have some problem with my pip installation. Both `pip` and `pip3` now means `pip3` in my bash commandline. When I type `pip -V` or `pip3 -V`, it shows the same information:

```
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

which means I can't use my python 2.7 pip.

The output from type -a gives the following:

```
$ type -a pip 
/usr/local/bin/pip 
$ type -a pip3 
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the output of "type -a pip" and "type -a pip3" ? Just to see what the commands are pointing at. Since it is /usr/local it looks like it is a localy installed version of pip, and not the system-installed version you are running. So $PATH might be the issue.

Comment: it is `pip is /usr/local/bin/pip` and `pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3`

Comment: Is that all of the content of "type -a pip" and "type -a pip3" ? If that is the case you don't have pip for the system-installed python 2 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather it sound like you don't have pip for Python 2.7 installed.

What is the output of `dpkg -l 'python-pip'`?

Since you have `Python 3 pip` installed under `/usr/local/bin` it sound like it is installed by you, manually, and not using the package system on Ubuntu.

**Install pip for Python 2.7**

To install `pip` for `Python 2.7` you can install it using `apt-get`

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

The output from `type -a pip` might now be something like this:

```
$ type -a pip
pip is /usr/local/bin/pip
pip is /usr/bin/pip
```

The second one is for `Python 2.7`.

```
$ /usr/bin/pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

This is controlled from the order the different paths is in your local $PATH envrionment. I have the following:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Any command in `/usr/local/bin` will be chosen before commands in `/usr/bin`. So to use pip for `Python 2.7` you'll have to use full path.

```
$ /usr/bin/pip
```